# UILocalNotification Repeat Once Weekly

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I would like to set a `UILocalNotification` that will automatically repeat once per week every Friday. I am currently using the code below to repeat a notification once per day at the same time but I am not sure how to create this for the week.

Thank you

```
let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
                let now: NSDate! = NSDate()
                let notifDate = calendar.dateBySettingHour(19, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchFirst)!

                var notification = UILocalNotification()
                notification.category = "Reminder"
                notification.alertTitle = "Alert"
                notification.alertBody = "Alert body"
                notification.fireDate = notifDate
                notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
                notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: Change repeatInterval to NSCalendarUnit. WeekOfYear. It will repeat every week at the same time.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a "NSCalendarUnit.Week". There is an error which says: Type 'NSCalendarUnit' has no member 'Week'

Comment: Its "NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear"

Answer (score 1):

Check [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit) here for UILocalNotification

This is how you would set it to repeat weekly.

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear;
```

PS. This code will create a notif on the day the notif is created and not just on Fridays. Something to consider.

```
let now: NSDate! = NSDate() //whatever today's day is and it could be any day between M-Sun
let notifDate = calendar.dateBySettingHour(19, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchFirst)!
```

Comment: When using the line about the error message changes to: Use of unresolved identifier 'kCFCalendarUnitWeek'

Comment: Try - NSWeekCalendarUnit